# Building a Vector quantizer with neurolab receiving an error

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, neurolab

Below is the code I am trying to execute, and the following error message I am receiving. Thank your for the assistance in advance.

----> 6 nn = nl.net.newlvq(nl.tool.minmax(data), num_input_neurons, weights)

```
# Define a neural network with 2 layers: 
# 10 neurons in input layer and 4 neurons in output layer
num_input_neurons = 10
num_output_neurons = 4
weights = [1/num_output_neurons] * num_output_neurons
nn = nl.net.newlvq(nl.tool.minmax(data), num_input_neurons, weights)
```

The error I receive:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: '----> 6 nn = nl.net.newlvq(nl.tool.minmax(data), num_input_neurons, weights)'

Answer (score 1):

Got this from: [python3中TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method 问题的修改办法](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_40592798/article/details/85678047)

1. Go to: `...\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\neurolab` or wherever your neurolab package is downloaded.
2. Open `net.py`
3. Go to line 179 and add `int()` to two locations. Just like this.

[image]

This worked for me.